# Deserializing partial XML segments into classes generated by XSD.exe

Tags: .net, xml

I have a number of XSD files that define the schema for some XML. I generated classes using the XSD.EXE tool and added this to my project.

The schema itself has a number of nested types that deserialize nicely, until I get to a segment defined like this:

```
    <xs:element name="SamplePayload" type="xs:anyType"/>
```

This leaves me with the raw System.Xml.XmlNode. I know the specific type/class this section should be deserialized as (it is specified in the XML itself and isn't static - it can be any of a few different types). I was hoping that I could just call Deserialize in the XmlSerializer class, passing in this segment, but of course it's not really valid XML on its own.

Is there an easy way I can load this segment into my classes without having to manually parse this stuff myself (this segment represents another fairly complex set of XML so that would be really painful).

I have no control over the XSD files so I can't just change them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I can think of is to write a preprocessor stage that simply replaces all instances of the string `xs:anyType` with your desired type.

You could also modify the generated classes to do the conversion on the fly.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could get that to work (easily) automatically, since I'm using XSD to generate the classes I need to deserialize into. I'd need to modify the XSD as you suggest, run XSD to generate the classes with the new known type, compile them, then continue with my code.

Comment: Or you could use XSD to generate the classes with the existing type, and then modify the class that handles `xs:anytype`.

Comment: I didn't originally specify this, but the type can change, and I know the type based on some other XML fields. I modified my question to make that a bit more clear.